# Pandas: Merge two dataframe with number of times the value in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

have got dataframe `df`

```
Aisle   Table_no    Table_Bit   
11          2           1
11          2           2
11          2           3
11          3           1
11          3           2
11          3           3
14          2           1
14          2           2
14          2           3
```

and another `spc_df`

```
Aisle   Table_no    Item    Item_time   Space
11      2           Mango       2       0.25
11      2           Lemon       1       0.125
11      3           Apple       3       0.75
14      2           Orange      1       0.125
14      2           Melon       2       0.25
```

need to add columns `spc_df['Item']` and `spc_df['Space']` to dataframe `df` with number of times the value in `spc_df['Item_time']` as given in expected output.
*Additional note(may/maynot used for logic):* Sum of Item_time for every Aisle-Table_no will be max of Table_Bit for that Aisle-Table_no combination.

**Expected Output:**

```
Aisle   Table_no    Table_Bit   Item    Space
11          2           1       Mango   0.25        
11          2           2       Mango   0.25                
11          2           3       Lemon   0.125       
11          3           1       Apple   0.75
11          3           2       Apple   0.75
11          3           3       Apple   0.75
14          2           1       Orange  0.125
14          2           2       Melon   0.25
14          2           3       Melon   0.25
```

Comment: Is column `Table_Bit` counter per groups in original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First repeat values in `spc_df` by `Item_time` with add counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), so possible left join by original `df` if `Table_Bit` is counter column starting by `1` per groups:

```
df2 = (spc_df.loc[spc_df.index.repeat(spc_df['Item_time'])]
           .assign(Table_Bit = lambda x: x.groupby(['Aisle','Table_no']).cumcount().add(1)))

df = df.merge(df2, how='left')
print (df)
   Aisle  Table_no  Table_Bit    Item  Item_time  Space
0     11         2          1   Mango          2  0.250
1     11         2          2   Mango          2  0.250
2     11         2          3   Lemon          1  0.125
3     11         3          1   Apple          3  0.750
4     11         3          2   Apple          3  0.750
5     11         3          3   Apple          3  0.750
6     14         2          1  Orange          1  0.125
7     14         2          2   Melon          2  0.250
8     14         2          3   Melon          2  0.250
```

If not `Table_ID` is counter column create helper column `new`:

```
df2 = (spc_df.loc[spc_df.index.repeat(spc_df['Item_time'])]
           .assign(new= lambda x: x.groupby(['Aisle','Table_no']).cumcount()))

df = (df.assign(new = df.groupby(['Aisle','Table_no']).cumcount())
        .merge(df2, how='left')
        .drop('new', axis=1))
print (df)
   Aisle  Table_no  Table_Bit    Item  Item_time  Space
0     11         2          1   Mango          2  0.250
1     11         2          2   Mango          2  0.250
2     11         2          3   Lemon          1  0.125
3     11         3          1   Apple          3  0.750
4     11         3          2   Apple          3  0.750
5     11         3          3   Apple          3  0.750
6     14         2          1  Orange          1  0.125
7     14         2          2   Melon          2  0.250
8     14         2          3   Melon          2  0.250
```

Comment: Second option fits perfect. Thank You for your help! :)